# Integration ActiveMQ service with web service (Mule ESB)

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jms, mule

I just want to send my web service data to ActiveMQ.
Problem is queue is not created and message is not sent to that queue. Here is my code:

```
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore"/>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="test_mq_externalwebserviceFlow1" doc:name="test_mq_externalwebserviceFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.org.RequestHandlerService" doc:name="SOAP"/> 
        <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" doc:name="Until Successful" deadLetterQueue-ref="retryFlow">
            <component class="com.org.ReverseName" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/> 
        </until-successful>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="errorQueue"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="errorQueue"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Please paste the log or describe why it is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Object to XML Transformer before JMS outbound endpoint and remove Jms endpoint after Java component ..... something like the following :-

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/><spring:beans>
<spring:bean id="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore"/</spring:beans><flow name="test_mq_externalwebserviceFlow1" doc:name="test_mq_externalwebserviceFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.org.RequestHandlerService" doc:name="SOAP"/> 
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" doc:name="Until Successful" deadLetterQueue-ref="retryFlow">
<component class="com.org.ReverseName" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/> 
</until-successful>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
  <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="errorQueue"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Now whenever exception will arise .. request will be send to ActiveMQ

Comment: Thanx for the reply..still having same problem..message is not sent to that queue...